# SQL: I need copy data from one field to another field in one table base on id of category

Tags: mysql

SQL: I need copy data from one field to another field in one table base on id of category

Like this (but this not work)

```
UPDATE z_jlogica_awards SET desc=desclong
FROM z_jlogica_awards WHERE z_jlogica_awards.parent='1';
```

[image]

Comment: can you post the schema for the 2 tables involved?

Comment: You can update your table by joining the other table. You should note that `desc` is a reserved keyword though

Comment: sorry this was old info i correct 1st post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query syntax is wrong.  try this:

UPDATE z_jlogica_awards SET longdesc=desc WHERE z_jlogica_awards.parent='1'

Comment: `UPDATE `z_jlogica_awards` SET `desc`=`longdesc` WHERE `z_jlogica_awards`.`parent`='1'`
ty  but all desc field is now empty))

here img http://clip2net.com/clip/m20850/938c9-clip-41kb.png

Comment: which two columns did you want to copy?  The previous query you executed copied longdesc into desc.

Comment: try this. UPDATE z_jlogica_awards SET longdesc=desc WHERE z_jlogica_awards.parent='1';

Comment: UPDATE `z_jlogica_awards` SET `longdesc`=`desc` WHERE `z_jlogica_awards`.`parent`='1'  ty this works

Comment: cool..  I have edited my answer to show the correct query.  can you please accept my answer